# Unit - тесты для C++ и Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, юнит-тесты

Всем привет! Необходимо сделать Unit - тесты. Какие тесты использовать для Xcode? Пробовал использовать Gtest но так и не смог их собрать, Xcode ругался на нехватку каких то файлов (скорее всего я что то делал не так). Может кто написать инструкцию по тому как поставить тот или иной framework для Unit - тестов на Xcode? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Начните с простейшего варианта, который не нужно собирать: [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2). Но в перспективе нужно собрать и GTest, не потому, что лучше, а потому, что нужно уметь собирать библиотеки и понимать почему они не собираются.

Comment: Пробовал использовать Catch 2. Скачал h файл, вроде как подключил его, а он ругается на нехватку файлов

Comment: Привет Max, я собрал для тебя простой тестовый пример Xcode/C++/Google Test. Я не могу ответить здесь, потому что вопрос заблокирован "требующими правки участниками". Вот ветка на гитхабе: https://github.com/stanislaw/Examples/tree/20190224-xcode-cpp-google-test-blank-project - там есть тестовый проект и инструкции в README файле. Буду рад помочь с ответами, ибо сам когда-то бился об эти грабли. Удачи.